# Optimizing animation - css or canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, css-animations

I'm creating personal web page, kinda portfolio, and I got idea of animation where many logos of tech things like node.js will be moving from down to up, here it is:

http://roman-k.herokuapp.com/

Sad but it consuming 70% in GPU process of my chrome on macbook and it's need to be optimized somehow, could you please share thoughts on how it could be done?

Currently it using requestAnimationFrame and ctx.drawImage on canvas for each logo.

I think I should place logos to some random positions with JS and then animate them with css, but how? Every logo will have random x and y position

Comment: Canvas is overkill for that. Take a look at existing css/js carousel/gallery/slider solutions. Basically you just need: a container with `overflow:hidden`, items in a row (column in your case), and movement handled by js and css.

Comment: What Brandon says too.  But you can just save the overall canvas drawing to cache it, and then just repaint that animating upwards.

Comment: I just remaked it to be 20 separate images and moving with css transition prop and chrome still shows GPU near 70%

Comment: can't you just make it one big image?  do the work offscreen and then copy it over.  but ya, if it's causing so much difficulty, you're better off just doing what Brandon said.  let the rendering engine do the work for you.  the coding for should be pretty straightforward

Comment: all you need is transition and top, hook animationend, and randomize left position.  will be a pretty quick css hack

Comment: @user120242 I did with transition but it was still consuming much GPU and was laggy when switching tabs

Comment: hm, did you try translateY3d with a div the size of the entire screen with all the images in it?

Comment: @user120242 by provided link there is no css transforms, it's working via canvas y position decreasing and redrawing of images. But I tried locally to draw canvas once and copy it to second canvas below first and translateY from down to up with keyframes and it still was to hard for my notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! and solved it. I removed all drawing and left just clearRect:

```
const animation = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
  animationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(animation)
}
animationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(animation)
```

This code just clears canvas and does nothing useful, however, it still loads GPU process by more than 50%.

To solve it I replaced `requestAnimationFrame` with `setInterval` which makes rendering fewer times, 20 times per second is enough for my animation, and now GPU feels much better.

P.S This problem could be chrome and mac specific, because this and other css animation work much smoother and better on android phone, on windows chrome and in firefox on macbook